# What query has to be generate so that all comments should sort along with their subcomments

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have a comment posting system in which different users post their comments. And also there is a subcomment feature, in which users give their subcomments also, like them, delete them too.

I store all comments and subcomments in one table named main_reviews which have a parent id field, by which I detect which is comment and which is subcomment. Main comment have a parent id value of 0, while subcomments have the parent id value of the id, of which they are subcomments.

So when I show all comments and subcomments on page using php function mysql_fetch_array(), I want to sort out all comments and subcomments using one query.
I used following query:

mysql_query("select * from main_reviews where p_id=0 order by id desc");

This display all correct data. But the twist is here: I want to sort all comments along with its subcomments, means when a user post a subcomment, that particular subcomment along with its main comment should be displayed on top like facebook.

So what query has to be generate whether using a 'union' or 'in' clause or anything else, so that all comments are sorted along with their subcomments, even if their subcomments are posted later.

And I am sorry, if there is any grammatical mistake, cause I am from a non english country.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "on top"? Also, how many levels deep can you post subcomments?

Comment: on top means order by descending. so all new comments should be displayed primariy.

Comment: So you mean that old toplevel posts come to the top when they have new comments?

Answer (score 0):

From a structural standpoint it would probably be better not to have comments and subcomments in the same table. I would seperate them into two tables so you have something like

```
Table comments
id (int,primary,auto increment)
body (text)
date (datetime)
```

and

```
Table subcomments
id (int,primary,auto increment)
comment_id (int,foreign key)
body (text)
date (datetime)
```

Using this structure, you can simply fire a query to get a comment and the according subcomments. Imagine you have a comment with the id 1, simply use

```
$query="SELECT * FROM subcomments WHERE comment_id=1 ORDER BY date DESC";
$result=mysql_query($query);
```

The `ORDER BY date DESC` will give you the latest subcomment first.

To get all comments and subcomments at once, use something like

```
SELECT * FROM comments,subcomments WHERE comments.id=subcomments.comment_id ORDER BY comments.date,subcomments.date
```

Comment: I disagree. Comments and sub-comments have a lot in common (author, date, content, etc).

Comment: No, I cant. I have to use only one table.
By the way thanks for your help.

Comment: I am not completely sure, but you could join the table on itself like SELECT b.* FROM comments b LEFT JOIN comments a ON b.id=a.parent_id ORDER BY b.date DESC

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of doing it in one query is to have all comments have the parent_id of the comments to have their own id rather than 0 (probably rename it to comment_id or something), then just sort by parent_id, and then by date. It's not very normalised, but that way you could do it in one query.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your best bet are two queries (assuming you can only reply to top-level comments).

Fetching the comments

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE parent_id = 0 ORDER BY date DESC
```

Fetching the subcomments:

```
SELECT * FROM WHERE parent_id <> 0 ORDER BY parent_id ASC, DATE DESC
```

You can then associate the subcomments easily within PHP.

On another note, I would use `NULL` to indicate that there is no parent post, not `0`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you have something like this: You have many subcomments with postingdates that you need to order your data. You want the latest postingdate (be it mainposting or the postingdate of a subposting) for certain orderings.

(short notation: maincomment = mc , subcomment = sc, mcid=is of mc, scid=id of sc)

Now restructure your resultset like this:

```
$mc = array();
// Loop over resultset here
foreach ($resultset as $onecomment){
 $mcid = ..(fetch from id or parentid from $onecomment)..
 if (..is_subcomment..){
   // put in subcomment of the right mc
   $mc[$mcid]["subcomment"][] = $onecomment;
 } else {
   // this is a maincommant
   $mc[$mcid] = $onecomment;
 }
 // And ALWAYS store the postdate, be it from the subcomment, of maincomment,
 // but only if it is later than the current
 if (!isset($mc[$mcid]["lastpostdate"])){
    // first, always store
    $mc[$mcid]["lastpostdate"] =  $onecomment["postdate"];
 } else {
    // Only store if this one is bigger
    if (strtotime($onecomment["postdate"]) > strtotime($mc[$mcid]["lastpostdate"])){
         // overwrite
         $mc[$mcid]["lastpostdate"] =  $onecomment["postdate"];
    }
 }
}
```

Now you have the last postdate of each posting stored.
Now you can use the $mc[$mcid]["lastpostdate"] to order your array on the lastpostdate.
The general idea of such restructuring is that you link the essential information (postdate) to the main-entry of the array.

Comment: Well, think of it this way: You need for every comment the latest postdate, right? Latest postdate must be the the date the comment is posted, OR ANY OF THE subcomments.
So you need to create somehow a one-to-one relationship between a maincomment, and the lastest postdate.
My example script did that in PHP: connect a mainposting to the lastest date belonging to that posting.